# Export to csv and import with same numerical precision?

Tags: r

When I export numeric data to a csv file and then import them back into R, they are not equal, as shown below.  What is the best way to check equality of these data without rounding arbitrarily?  Or is there a good way of exporting numeric data to a csv file and later importing them and checking whether they are exactly equal to a new result?  I'm open to solutions that involve exporting or importing the data differently to and from a csv or tab-delimited file.

```
set.seed(10)
x = rnorm(1)
write.csv(x, "test.csv", row.names = F)
y = read.csv("test.csv")
x == y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ...

```
write.csv(format(x, digits = 17), "test.csv", row.names = F)
```

...?

As I had to figure out anyways:
Form [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html):
"It is a historical anomaly that R has two names for its floating-point vectors, `double` and `numeric` (and formerly had `real`). `double` is the name of the type. `numeric` is the name of the mode and also of the implicit class."

The real precision on your computer depends on your machine, see `.Machine`

Comment: I like your answer.  I was looking for something simple like that.  Any reason why 17 is a good choice?

Comment: See my edits. format(x, digits = 22) is the maximum, displaying 18 digits.

Comment: `numeric` uses a double-precision floating-point format which based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format has 15-17 significant decimal digits.

Comment: Ok, digits = 17 and above work for me.  Can this number be determined?  I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the byte size information in .Machine.

Comment: Interesting question, unfortunatelly I don't know the answer. I think, the precision is more than enough on most PC... By the way: RData has the advantage, that data is compressed, so less memory is needed! If you are only working within R I would use that.

Answer (score 1):

If the data doesn't have to be saved as `.csv`, then it is probably best to save the data as `.RData` using `save` then `load` it whenever needed.

```
set.seed(10)
x = rnorm(1)
x2 = x
save(x2, file = "x.RData")
rm(x2)
load("x.RData")

> identical(x, x2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know, but I am specifically interested in data exported to csv or tab-delimited files.  I edited the question.