# How to avoid: read.table truncate last digits after decimal

Tags: r, truncate

I want to import a table (.txt file) in R with read.table().

```
table1<- read.table("input.txt",sep = "\t")
```

The file contains data like `0.09165395632583884`

After reading the data, data becomes `0.09165396`. Last few digits are lost,
but I want to avoid this problem.

If I used

```
options(digits=22)
```

then it creates another problem, like maindata = `0.19285969062961023` but when I write the data in file,

```
write.table(table1,file = "output.txt",col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

I get data = `0.192859690629610225`. Here, last digit is extra and the second last digit is change.

Can someone give me a hint how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's truncating, and not just not printing them? `print(d , digits = 16)`

Comment: It is not duplicate. I need this solution . I modify the question.

Comment: Welcome to floating point representation. [The links here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558) explain what's happening. The simplest (if hacky) solution is just to store your numbers as strings.

Comment: Although, this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694066/export-to-csv-and-import-with-same-numerical-precision/37694705#37694705) is about csv, it should help as the idea is the same.